# JTable cell too high? CustomTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I've tried modifying the table cell size especially the preferredSize().height code and it just ends up either too high or wont go multiline.

all I want to do is get the cell to fit the content and I've been doing this for three hours now >_<

fyi this is a multiline cell render. thanks!
here is my code:

```
package testpackage;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestRender extends JFrame {

    public TestRender() {
        JTable jTable1 = new JTable(){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
                return true;
            }
        };

        jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd", null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));

        jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TextWrapCellRenderer());

        for (int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++){
            int rowHeight = jTable1.getRowHeight();

            for (int column = 0; column < jTable1.getColumnCount(); column++){
                Component comp = jTable1.prepareRenderer(jTable1.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
            }

            jTable1.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
        }

        jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout());
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jTable1));
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestRender().show();
    }
}
class TextWrapCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TextWrapCellRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setText((String)value);
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),this.getPreferredSize().height);
        setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);

        if (isSelected){
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        }else{
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

[Here's what it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbJON.png)

**UPDATE 1:**
Adding a instantiated row will yield multiline effect as intended. but the row height is still too high leaving a blank space.

**UPDATE 2:**
Adding a row via runtime does not yield the multiline effect, rather is displays as a standard row.

```
btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)->{
            Object[] row = {null,"uydfaiywhdfwaywefgihaasdfadsfadsfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfadsfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdfadsfjewfkuaywehfijlawkhrfuioaewjfhygkualiowjkharlufih",null,null};
            ((DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel()).addRow(row);
        });
```

**EDIT 3**

I changed my TableCellRenderer to this:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }else{
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        setFont(table.getFont());

        if (hasFocus) {
            setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
            if (table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
                setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellForeground"));
                setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellBackground"));
            }
        } else {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 2, 1, 2));
        }
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        int x = this.getLineCount();
        table.setRowHeight(row, x);
        return this;
    }
```

aiming that the renderer will change the height based on the lines of jtextarea. but it seems the row's height became zero. maybe I placed it in the wrong block? I needed each row's height to depend on the number of lines in a jtextarea.

**UPDATE 4**
still a dead end.

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    MultiLineTableCustomizer mltc = new MultiLineTableCustomizer();
    public NewJFrame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")              
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MultiLineCellRendererx());
        jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                refreshTable(jTable1);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setLineWrap(true);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jTextArea2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 359, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }                     

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Object[] row = {jTextArea1.getText(), jTextArea2.getText()};
        ((DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel()).addRow(row);
        refreshTable(jTable1);
    }                                        
    public void refreshTable(JTable jTable1){
        for (int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++){
            int rowHeight = jTable1.getRowHeight();

            for (int column = 0; column < jTable1.getColumnCount(); column++){
                JTextArea comp = (JTextArea)jTable1.prepareRenderer(jTable1.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                if(rowHeight<((comp.getLineCount()+1)*30)){
                    rowHeight = (comp.getLineCount()+1)*30;
                }
            }
            jTable1.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: How should it look like? Can you post an image / ascii art?

Comment: added a picture as requested. still not able to solve the issue.

Comment: That's how it looks like now, but, how **should** it look like?

Comment: If with *"all I want to do is get the cell to fit the content"* is to make the blue selection for the "asdf" part well, maybe if you add more rows into your table it could fix the issue, sorry I can't code atm

Comment: I need it to fit based on the content of the JTextArea. but I have absolutely no idea how this time.

Comment: I mean set the row height based on the content of the jTextArea.
EDIT: tested out adding another row. still yields the same result. same goes, the added row is also too high but not as high as the first one. its like 10 or 15 /n

Comment: I found 2 links: [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiLineCellExample.htm) and [this one](http://esus.com/embedding-a-jtextarea-in-a-jtable-cell/) try them, as I said I can't code but maybe that could help

Comment: thank you. any suggestions that might help is appreciated!

Comment: I could see that the examples given instantiates either number of lines or row height. Guess this is not the right one. either way, thank you very much for helping out.

Comment: Get the number of lines in your text area and use that

Comment: awesome clue!. I took the number of lines inside the jtextarea in the tablecellrenderer, so far, I tried setting the table row's height by using `table.setRowHeight(row,this.getLineCount());` but the row height became zero even though its returning 4 or 6 depending on the length of the input. any way around this? by the way, this is per row. so the row's height will depend on the length of the content

Comment: I think im getting somewhere. but do you mind explaining to me what this `Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);` does? does it return the jTextArea?

Comment: updated. still in a dead end. T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kudos to you @Frakcool

you made this possible for me. thank you! I hope you can post an answer and I'll mark it.

here is the result:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

/**
 *
 * @author Innocentus
 */
public class MultiLineJTable extends JTable{

    public MultiLineJTable(){
        super();
    }

    public MultiLineJTable(Object[][] row, String[] col){
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(row,col);
        this.setModel(dtm);
        addFireEvent();
        this.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MultiLineCellRendererx());
    }

    @Override
    public void setModel(TableModel dataModel) {
        if (dataModel == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set a null TableModel");
        }
        if (this.dataModel != dataModel) {
            TableModel old = this.dataModel;
            if (old != null) {
                old.removeTableModelListener(this);
            }
            this.dataModel = dataModel;
            dataModel.addTableModelListener(this);

            tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(dataModel, TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW));

            firePropertyChange("model", old, dataModel);

            if (getAutoCreateRowSorter()) {
                setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(dataModel));
            }
            addFireEvent();
        }  
        try {
            this.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MultiLineCellRendererx());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void refreshTable(){
        JTable tbl = this;
        for (int row = 0; row < tbl.getRowCount(); row++){
            int rowHeight = tbl.getRowHeight();

            for (int column = 0; column < tbl.getColumnCount(); column++){
                Component comp = tbl.prepareRenderer(tbl.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
            }

            tbl.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
        }
    }

    private void addFireEvent(){
        this.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

                switch (e.getType()) {
                    case TableModelEvent.DELETE:
                        refreshTable();
                        break;
                    case TableModelEvent.INSERT:
                        refreshTable();
                        break;
                    case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                        refreshTable();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
class MultiLineCellRendererx extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {

    public MultiLineCellRendererx() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setText((String)value);
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),this.getPreferredSize().height);
        setSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);

        if (isSelected){
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        }else{
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help anymore because I had an exam today so I had to study, I'm arriving home so I came to see if you were able to solve it and I saw you could! Congratulations! :)

Comment: thank you! with your help, I was able to solve it. that was even better than just providing a coded solution. it got me worked up and made me understand custom table render even more! now I'm rendering custom controls and even finally learned how to use custom table editors. I owe you a lot, thank you!

Comment: I won't post an answer because yours is better 'cause it has code so, accept it, there's no shame in doing so :) glad I could help anyway

Comment: Instead of adding an edit that you posted an answer, [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)